Error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toUpperCase')" in WSO2 IS 7.0.0 Console when viewing user roles
I am using WSO2 IS 7.0.0 and encountered an issue in the new admin console.
After logging in with the default credentials (admin/admin), when I try to view the roles of a specific user, I receive the following error message:
"Something went wrong while displaying this page. See the browser console for technical details."
Example Image Error WSO2 Roles
In the Chrome console, the error displayed is:
vendor.36d2e198.js?e53d719344b5ee54:102 
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toUpperCase')
    at render (main.285d3e4b.js?e53d719344b5ee54:2:2296498)
    at main.285d3e4b.js?e53d719344b5ee54:2:3286071
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at main.285d3e4b.js?e53d719344b5ee54:2:3285885
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at e (main.285d3e4b.js?e53d719344b5ee54:2:3285650)
    at Za (vendor.36d2e198.js?e53d719344b5ee54:102:1605906)
    at Es (vendor.36d2e198.js?e53d719344b5ee54:102:1617537)
    at Zl (vendor.36d2e198.js?e53d719344b5ee54:102:1663628)
    at xc (vendor.36d2e198.js?e53d719344b5ee54:102:1651913)

When I check the wso2carbon.log, I encounter the following error message:
[-1234] [scim2] [2024-06-12 07:08:25,066] [6f05e984-30e9-48ca-8c13-e7112b977a66] ERROR {org.wso2.charon3.core.protocol.endpoints.AbstractResourceManager} - Error occurred while retrieving the role list of user. org.wso2.charon3.core.exceptions.CharonException
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.scim2.common.impl.SCIMRoleManagerV2.prepareAddedRemovedUserLists(SCIMRoleManagerV2.java:1305)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.scim2.common.impl.SCIMRoleManagerV2.updateUsers(SCIMRoleManagerV2.java:1073)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.scim2.common.impl.SCIMRoleManagerV2.patchRole(SCIMRoleManagerV2.java:427)
    at org.wso2.charon3.core.protocol.endpoints.RoleResourceV2Manager.updateWithPatchOperations(RoleResourceV2Manager.java:564)
    at org.wso2.charon3.core.protocol.endpoints.RoleResourceV2Manager.updateWithPATCHRole(RoleResourceV2Manager.java:310)
    at org.wso2.charon3.core.protocol.BulkRequestProcessor.getBulkResponseContent(BulkRequestProcessor.java:261)
    at org.wso2.charon3.core.protocol.BulkRequestProcessor.processBulkRequests(BulkRequestProcessor.java:197)
    at org.wso2.charon3.core.protocol.endpoints.BulkResourceManager.processBulkData(BulkResourceManager.java:84)
    at org.wso2.charon3.core.protocol.endpoints.BulkResourceManager.processBulkData(BulkResourceManager.java:59)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.scim2.provider.resources.BulkResource.createUser(BulkResource.java:73)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:179)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:201)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:104)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:265)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:225)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:304)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:217)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:555)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.doFilter(ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:129)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:596)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:119)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.OrganizationContextRewriteValve.invoke(OrganizationContextRewriteValve.java:123)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.SameSiteCookieValve.invoke(SameSiteCookieValve.java:38)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.cors.valve.CORSValve.invoke(CORSValve.java:83)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:183)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:144)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:110)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:71)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:152)
    at org.wso2.carbon.extension.identity.x509Certificate.valve.X509CertificateAuthenticationValve.invoke(X509CertificateAuthenticationValve.java:59)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:670)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:63)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestEncodingValve.invoke(RequestEncodingValve.java:49)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:928)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1794)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

I have verified that the credentials and permissions are correct.
Has anyone experienced the same issue or knows how to resolve it?

As per the error log printed in the terminal, seems you have tried scim2 bulk endpoint to create users with assigning roles for them. Could you please provide the sample that you tried out
